# Evaluating an expression from the server with Angular 2

Tags: angular

I am writing an application where I need to pass an ngIf expression from inside a method. Expression is coming from backend service as string. In Angular 1, I used to use interpolation to evaluate the string before passing to ng-if which then used to get evaluated as true or false, look at plunker below

**UPDATED**

Plunker Angular 1.5
https://plnkr.co/edit/ukGlJvBZyqGvvrmjEZJY?p=preview

But in Angular 2 , I can not use interpolation with *ngIf, throws exception. Look at the below code. I am expecting none of the lines (Howdy1, Howdy2, Howdy3) appear on UI as passing same expression. But only 1st one is hidden not remaining two where expression is passed as a string variable.

I have plunker code for both Angular 2 and 1.5. If anyone solved similar problem, please help me.

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Angular 2 Systemjs start</h1>
    <div *ngIf="map['a']=='b' || map['b']=='a'">Howdy1</div>
    <div *ngIf="logicAsString">Howdy2</div>
    <div *ngIf="showDiv(logicAsString)">Howdy3</div>
    <p>{{logicAsString}}</p>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  logicAsString:string ="map['a']=='b' || map['b']=='a'";

  map = {
    a:'a',
    b:'b'
  }

  public showDiv(logic){
    return logic; 
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Plunker Angular 2- 
 https://plnkr.co/edit/YExzpE?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Using the new Function syntax in JavaScript, you could change your showDiv function to:

```
public showDiv (logic) {
   let myfunc = new Function ('map', logic);
   let myresult:boolean = myfunc (this.map);
   return myresult;
}
```

And you'd also have to change the logicAsString to:

```
logicAsString:string = "if (map['a'] == 'c') return true; return false;"
```

so it would return the boolean to the caller.   This really just wraps your existing logicAsString so you could even do this inside the showDiv function.

And this doesn't use eval, which many people dislike.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I like your solution. Seems it's somehow better than eval :) If anyone like me who does not know much about Function in javascript may look at this link http://www.2ality.com/2014/01/eval.html

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to output the expression as raw HTML from the server, 
then you can simply do:

```
<div *ngIf="SERVEROUTPUT"></div>
```

or you will need to use the [eval function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) that's native to javascript.

Comment: It's little more complex than I explained initially. In my case the logic is coming from backend as a string. To mimic the situation I created below plunker. You can see "Howdy1" does not get render which is expected. Similarly I was expecting "Howdy2" and "Howdy3" disappear but they are not. plnkr.co/edit/YExzpE?p=preview

Comment: That Plunker is Angular 1.5 and it has a JavaScript error on it?

Comment: I saw that, I mistakenly used ng-if instead of ng-show. Plunker is updated. As ng-show is not available in angular 2, I tried [hidden] and *ngIf but both did not work. I found if I change the showHide() method in angular 2 plunker to return eval(logic) instead of simply logic, it works. But kind of skeptical using eval. Any thoughts?  Plunker of updated code https://plnkr.co/edit/KxVor9?p=preview

Comment: You can simply go <div *ngIf="map['a']=='a'">Howdy2</div>. That will evaluate it correctly? If you need to output the string from the server then you'll need to do something like: <div *ngIf="SERVEROUPUT"></div> where SERVEROUTPUT is map['a'] == 'a'

Comment: In the plunker I tried to mimic exactly same as you explained. logicAsString is the SERVEROUTPUT there. Problem is, when you write the expression directly inside html it works but when you pass it as a string variable it does not. String variable is always evaluated as true and the expression inside string does not get evaluated.

Comment: The only way to do it is either output it as raw HTML from the server, or you'll need to use the eval function in js.

Comment: you are right. That's what I found. Let's see if anyone has different thought. For time  being I am buying eval. Seems someone through it's a stupid question to ask and down-voted my question :) Btw, thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: haha no problem :-) Good luck! Will update answer in question anyways, I'll edit the title of the question too to make it a bit more precise

Answer (score 0):

The eval function in JavaScript will work to execute the logicAsString that you've created above.

```
<div *ngIf="eval(logicAsString)">Howdy2</div>
<div *ngIf="eval(showDiv(logicAsString))">Howdy3</div>
```

Eval is a function that a lot of people don't like but at least works.  JavaScript has a new Function syntax that I played with but couldn't find the magical syntax to make it work right here that you may find is more acceptable.

If I can make new Function work, I'll post that answer as well.

This solution allows you to build logicAsString however you wish and allows it to be modified at run time.   It's a plus for the solution, but also a minus from a security perspective.

Comment: Yes eval does the trick but I am hesitating to use eval, for some obvious reason you know :)  I will be interested in the other solution without eval.